# How to tell PHP which comments to show under the article with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am building a news page for my website but I'm stuck displaying the right comments with ajax...

**commentsLoad.php**

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$newsid = $_GET['newsid'];

    $comments=array();
    $commentsQuery = "SELECT * FROM comments
    where fk_news like ".$newsid;
    $result = $conn->query($commentsQuery);
        if($result->num_rows>0){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                 $comments[]=array('id' => $row['id'], 'name' => $row['cnick'], 'text' => $row['ctext'], 'date' => $row['cdate']);                                                                      
            }
        }
                    //header('Content-type: application/json');
                    echo json_encode($comments);
                    exit;
?>
```

I dont know how to pass the right **'NEWSID'.**

Website picture: http://prntscr.com/8nwy8k

**How I want to pass that ID to the SQL Query**

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: commentsUrl,
 dataType: "json",
 data:{newsid:'1'},
 success: function(comments){
    //console.log(komentarji);
    $.each(comments, function(i, komentar){
        addComment(komentar);
 })
},
error: function(e){
    console.log(e);
 }              
});
```

So right now if I change the line **data:{newsid:'1 or 2 or 3...'}** I get the comments I want, but I dont know how to get that ID into a variable.

Comment: are you using any loop to show your articles?

Comment: Hi, Use onclick function in Comments link .

Comment: Yes, the first code block in my post, while loop into an JSON array I think that is.

@Karthik and how do I get news ID if im not displaying it?

Comment: First Try get get the newsid article posted page.

Comment: Just on a side note, your query is vulnerable to sql injections. Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onClick event for this.

Explanation:

`Comment` link will look as follows

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="getComments('<?php echo $YOUR_ARTICLE_ ID?>')">Comments</a>
```

Then you can have a fucntion in your JQuery code to pass it to PHP file.

```
function getComments(article_id)
{
    var artid = article_id;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: commentsUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        data:{newsid: artid},
        success: function(comments){
            $.each(comments, function(i, komentar){
                addComment(komentar);
            })
        },
        error: function(e){
            console.log(e);
        }              
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, ids are supposed to be unique. If there are more than one article at the page your code will fail. It's better to add a class to the element and bind it to a click event and then use `$(this).data('artid')` to retrieve the id.

Comment: Im gonna do this in a sec, i have a few syntax problems at <?php

Answer (score 0):

Try set onclick function in the comment link.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='myfunction <?php echo newsid ?>'Comment</a>
```

Get the `newsid` form the link.

```
<script>
function myfunction(newsid){
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: commentsUrl,
dataType: "json",
data:{newsid:newsid},
success: function(comments){
//console.log(komentarji);
$.each(comments, function(i, komentar){
    addComment(komentar);
})
},
error: function(e){
console.log(e);
}              
});
}
</script>
```

Get the newid from commenntsUrl page.